# Passing args and stdin from main to a class

Tags: java

Can someone give me an example, based on what I have, on how to pass the command line args or stdin from main to the class named drawOnGrid? I am having a hard time understanding it. Basically I need to use "g.drawString (argOne, 10, 10);" instead of drawOval or drawLine. I have enclosed my code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Tictactoe extends JFrame {

//construct a figurePanel
public Tictactoe() {

    Container RandomTicTacToePanel = getContentPane();
    RandomTicTacToePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));


    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        RandomTicTacToePanel.add(new drawOnGrid());
    }
}

//Main method
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String argOne;
    String argTwo;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int length = args.length;
    if (length <= 0) {
        System.out.println("Please enter player One's symbol: ");
        argOne = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter player Two's symbol: ");
        argTwo = in.nextLine();
        in.close();
    }

    Tictactoe Tframe = new Tictactoe();
    Tframe.setTitle("Tic Tac Toe Panel: Random Entries");
    Tframe.setSize(350, 350);
    Tframe.setResizable(true);
    Tframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    Tframe.setVisible(true);
    Tframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

class drawOnGrid extends JPanel {

    //overide the paintComponent
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        int random = (int) (Math.random() * 3);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

                if (random == 0) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                } else if (random == 1) {
                    g.drawOval(10, 10, getWidth() - 20, getHeight() - 20);
                } else if (random == 2) {
                    g.drawLine(10, 10, getWidth() - 10, getHeight() - 10);
                    g.drawLine(getWidth() - 10, 10, 10, getHeight() - 10);

                }
            }

        }
    }
}
}
```

I would really appreciate it. Thank You.

Comment: You can pass `args` directly, and/or pass your local variables directly, to a method via the same mechanism any method uses to get parameters.

Comment: You can create a `String[]` attribute for the `drawOnGrid` class and either pass `args` in via a constructor or via a setter.

Comment: @JackManey can you show me a non-elaborate example?

Comment: @user1646877 - aymeric's answer is prettymuch the same as the example that I would've given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Tictactoe extends JFrame {

//construct a figurePanel
public Tictactoe(String text) {

    Container RandomTicTacToePanel = getContentPane();
    RandomTicTacToePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));


    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        RandomTicTacToePanel.add(new drawOnGrid(text));
    }
}

//Main method
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String argOne = null; // Init with null
    String argTwo = null; // Init with null

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int length = args.length;
    if (length <= 0) {
        System.out.println("Please enter player One's symbol: ");
        argOne = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter player Two's symbol: ");
        argTwo = in.nextLine();
        in.close();
    } else if(length == 1) {
        argOne = args[0];
    } else if(length == 2) {
        argOne = args[0];
        argTwo = args[1];
    }

    Tictactoe Tframe = new Tictactoe(argOne);
    Tframe.setTitle("Tic Tac Toe Panel: Random Entries");
    Tframe.setSize(350, 350);
    Tframe.setResizable(true);
    Tframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    Tframe.setVisible(true);
    Tframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

class drawOnGrid extends JPanel {

    private String text;

    public drawOnGrid(String text) {
       this.text = text;
    }

    //overide the paintComponent
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        int random = (int) (Math.random() * 3);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

                if (random == 0) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                } else if (random == 1) {
                    g.drawOval(10, 10, getWidth() - 20, getHeight() - 20);
                } else if (random == 2) {
                    g.drawLine(10, 10, getWidth() - 10, getHeight() - 10);
                    g.drawLine(getWidth() - 10, 10, 10, getHeight() - 10);

                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! you have been "arrowed" up.

Comment: Tried what you did and get an error on this line `Tictactoe Tframe = new Tictactoe(argOne);` stating `error: variable argOne might not have been initialized
    Tictactoe Tframe = new Tictactoe(argOne); ` Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you, I assume that if I want the 2nd command line arg I need to create another varible called text2? I used the first variable text in my g.drawString(text, 10, 10) method.

Comment: Exactly :) Good luck for the rest!